# How to create environment specific spring boot jar file name with gradle

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have a requirement to create spring boot jar file name based upon the environments. The environment can be **dev** or **prod**. When I run with the command `gradlew clean build`, it generates **app-service-0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.jar**. As per my requirement, it should be **app-service-0.0.1.SNAPSHOT.jar** for dev environment and **app-service-0.0.1.jar** for prod environment. How can I customize the naming of spring boot jar file in gradle? Please help me. I have also tried in the following manner, it did not work.

```
... other gradle code ....
ext {
    isProd = System.properties['env'] == 'prod'
    isDev = System.properties['env'] == 'dev'
}

//if (isDev) tasks.withType(jar).all { it.enabled = false }

task dev(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar) {
    baseName = 'custom-spring-boot'
    /*
    bootJar {
        archiveFileName = 'my-awesome-app.jar'
    }
    */
}

/*
bootJar {
    if (env == 'dev') {
        archiveFileName = 'my-awesome-app.jar'
    } else {
        archiveFileName = 'hati-app.jar'
    }
   
}
*/

tasks.addRule("Pattern: bootJar<ENV>") { String taskName ->
    if (taskName.startsWith('bootJar')) {
        def env = (taskName - 'bootJar').toLowerCase()
        if (env in ['dev', 'prod',]) {
          task(taskName, type: bootJar) {
              println "Configuring env: $env"
              from("src/main/conf/$env") {
                  into("conf")
              }
          }
        } else {
          println "Invalid env: $env, skipping."
        }
    }
    }
```

I also checked with this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278999/how-to-override-a-gradle-build-with-dev-prod-configuration)

Comment: Just in case you haven't considered it: another approach is to put all configuration files in the same jar, with the environment name added as a suffix to each configuration, and then selecting the correct one through profiles at runtime. I like it better than producing environment-specific runtimes. BTW, you are missing the link to the SO post you reference at the end.

Comment: Thanks @BjørnVester, I have added the missing link. I want the name to be changed while the Gradle command like this `gradlew clean build dev` or `gradlew clean build prod`

Comment: Seems like you want to have different versions, not names of the jar in total? Because the full name of the archive is contatenation of `[archiveBaseName]-[archiveAppendix]-[archiveVersion]-[archiveClassifier].[archiveExtension]`

Comment: For me `bootJar {
    if (env == 'dev') {
        archiveFileName = 'my-awesome-app.jar'
    } else {
        archiveFileName = 'hati-app.jar'
    }
   
}` works as expected (if you want to change the full archive name). Post gradle version.

Comment: Hi @michalk, I am using Gradle latest version 6.6.1. I have already tried to execute the script suggested by you, but it did not work. Now I am left with only last option where I have to copy the boot jar file location and I need to rename it with a gradle task. Request you suggest me other best practices.